# "Cannot GET /" Error with Firebase Functions and Express.js

Tags: express, google-cloud-functions, next.js

I'm trying to give access rights to my web app to users on the whitelist ip address list. My web app is hosted on Firebase Hosting and I'm using Next.js.

Since I can't do it with Firebase Hosting, I'm using Firebase Functions. Here is my function.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const requestIp = require('request-ip');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const whiteList = ['222.222.222.222', '111.111.111.111'];

app.get('/', (request, response, next) => {
    // const clientIp = requestIp.getClientIp(request);
    const clientIp = '222.222.222.222'; // Hard coded value for testing purpose
    if (whiteList.includes(clientIp))  {
        next()
    } else {
        response.status(403).send('Access denied.');
    }
});

exports.filter = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

And this is my firebase.json.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "out",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "filter"
      }
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

My pages structure is like this.

```
/pages
   /index.tsx
   /about.tsx
```

When I access about.tsx, this error shows up.

> Cannot GET /about

I placed the pages directory under src, and exported files are in out directory.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you get more information in the logs that could help to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Yes. From the Functions logs? When I accessed the page, all I get is this. > Function execution took 10 ms, finished with status code: 404